# Symfony2 datetime form

Tags: php, symfony, datetime

Something strange hppning with my datetime field in form. **I've just updated php version to 5.5.29**

Form field:

```
$customerReportForm->add('dateTo', 'date', [
    'data' => new \DateTime(),
    'required' => false,
    'widget' => 'single_text',
    'label' => 'До',
    'attr' => array('class' => 'datepicker', "data-date-format" => "yy-mm-dd")
]);
```

in dev-console I see **form[dateTo]:2015-09-18**
and while mking dump of form data(after submit), I see the date with day before I've selected:

**2015-09-17**

 `["dateTo"]=> object(DateTime)#436 (3) { ["date"]=> string(26) "2015-09-17 23:00:00.000000" ["timezone_type"]=> int(3) ["timezone"]=> string(13) "Europe/Moscow" }`

In console date command showing me right date:

`-> % date
Pn Rgs 18 13:00:29 MSK 2015`

*In form I've try to add: 'format' => 'MM/dd/yyyy', it'd didn't help, post data: form[dateTo]:09/18/2015*

---

***UPD***

Thanks to [John Noel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4545769/john-noel), **reconfigured timezone to UTC** and

```
'model_timezone' => 'UTC',
'view_timezone' => 'UTC',
```

in form fixed my problem.

Comment: Try  changing the date seperators to / and let me know how it went

Comment: Thy are http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/15/0918/h_1442570800_2664789_e6769a096b.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds a lot like either a timezone or a locale issue.

The former can be checked with the [two options](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/date.html#view-timezone) `model_timezone` and `view_timezone` on your form field, e.g.

```
$customerReportForm->add('dateTo', 'date', [
    // ...
    'model_timezone' => 'UTC',
    'view_timezone' => 'UTC',
]);
```

Try setting the timezone that way to UTC and see if you still get the same issue. Next, try looking at your system (not PHP) timezone then make sure that the `date.timezone` setting in your php.ini file matches this. If none of this helps, it may be the locale.

Internally the `date` field uses `Locale` and `IntlDateFormatter` instances to make sure that dates and times are formatted and read in correctly. PHP uses [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) for this. There are several points that an issue like this could be making itself known:

1. Your system / php.ini / Symfony config locales differ in strange ways
2. If your version of PHP is compiled against a weird or buggy version of ICU
3. The locales stored on your system may not be up to date or again, may be buggy

Anything beyond this is speculation. I've run into a similar issue you describe with a timezone switch from UTC to Europe/London which are in sync depending on DST. I very much doubt it's locale bugginess, but if you're sure you're not manipulating the dates in anyway, it can't hurt to check.

Comment: 'model_timezone' => 'UTC',
    'view_timezone' => 'UTC',
made it! Thanks dude!

Timezone in php.ini is set to Eourope\Moscrow